# Best way to get all digits from a string

Tags: c#, regex, text-parsing

Is there any better way to get take a string such as "(123) 455-2344" and get "1234552344" from it than doing this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

return String.Join(string.Empty, matches.Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
```

Perhaps a regex pattern that can do it in a single match? I couldn't seem to create one to achieve that though.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Do you need to use a Regex?

```
return new String(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: +1, good idea. You left out a bit of the lambda inside the where, though. `.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c))`

Comment: Didn't consider approaching this from the char level.

Comment: @Anthony No, my syntax works fine, and is less "noisy" than the expanded version.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I had not tried it that way.

Comment: Upvote for "Do you need to use a Regex" :D

Comment: does this handle floating point and negative numbers?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon No, `char.IsDigit('.')` and `char.IsDigit('-')` both return `false`.

Comment: Hell yeah my man, Screw regex :)

Answer (score 24):

Have you got something against `Replace`?

```
return Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9]+", "");
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to replace `/\D/` (non-digit) with `''` (empty string)

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\D");
string s = Regex.Replace("(123) 455-2344", r, "");
```

Or more succinctly:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("(123) 455-2344", @"\D",""); //return only numbers from string
```

Comment: I like this answer. However, between this one and the accepted answer, are there significant difference beside one using Regex and another isn't?

Answer (score 7):

Just remove all non-digits:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl (you can adapt this to C#) simply do

```
$str =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
```

I am assuming that your string is in $str. Basic idea is to replace all non digits with '' (i.e. empty string)