# Converting string to integer by selecting the elements to stay

Tags: c#

I have to eliminate all special characters, alphabets and keep only the numbers in the string and store it into an integer. For example "$67%!" or "$127a%". I am obtaining data from serial port and in certain cases there are alphabets/ special chars between $ and % or may be a number after %. Currently, I have this snippet with me

```
string UartInput = serialcom.ReadLine();
int[] ints = UartInput.Trim(new[] { '$', '%' }).Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

I made a few needed changes and transmitted a single value at a time. The snippet was changed to

```
int ints = Convert.ToInt16(serialcom.ReadLine().Trim(new[] { '$', '%' }))
```

It was insufficient

Comment: Probably this is the best use case for a regex expression

Comment: If you want just the numbers from the string then there are threads on this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634731/best-way-to-get-all-digits-from-a-string

Comment: Maybe I'm not orthodox, why not minimal loop? Full debugging capabilities etc ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get all digits from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634731/best-way-to-get-all-digits-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
string serialcomnum = Regex.Match(serialcom,"\\d+").ToString();
int ints = Convert.ToInt32(serialcomnum);
```

Another way could be

```
string serialcom = "$67%!$127a%";
var serialcomnum = Regex.Replace(serialcom, @"[^0-9]+", ",");
serialcomnum = serialcomnum.TrimStart(',').TrimEnd(',');
int[] serialints = serialcomnum.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow. Could you please explain that \\d part?

Comment: \d is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and + means 1 or more times. So, \d+ is 1 or more digits. @Anand

Comment: Why not use `Convert.ToInt32()` and instead using 'ToInt16()'?

Comment: BTW, your code will not work if the user is expecting more than one integer in the string.

Comment: @Ghasan That is y i added another way. And yes lemme change it to 32 instead of 16

Comment: the data transmitted is 16 bits, so it is received as int16, not int32

Comment: Yes, the method I mentioned will not work when an array is being transmitted. I am aware. I am not expecting more than one integer to be transmitted at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a simple Regex is the easiest solution without using other string parsing methods

```
string input = "$67%!$127a%";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray();

foreach (int x in result)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Here the example expects more than one number inside your input string and returns an array of integers. If this is not the case (only one integer expected) then you can replace the `ToArray` with a `SingleOrDefault()` and assign the result to an integer variable.

Also, if you have numbers bigger than `Int32.MaxValue`, then you should change the `Int32.Parse` with `Int64.Parse`.

Comment: Probably using `\d` is better here.

Comment: Uhm, I think \d is less efficient unless you need to parse numbers in specific locales  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but i think it might work

```
int result = Int32.Parse(string.Concat(yourStringVarible.ToCharArray().TakeWhile(char.IsNumber)));
```

EDIT:

For getting the ints enclosed by other chars (not tested aswell):

```
public List<int> GetInts(string text){
 char[] chars = text.ToCharArray()
 bool prevIsNum = false;
 int startI = 0;
 int lenI = 0;
 List<int> ints = new List<int>();
 for(i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
    if(Char.IsNumber(chars[i])){
        if(prevIsNum){
            lenI ++;
        }else{
            startI = i;
            lenI ++;
        }
        prevIsNum = true;
    }else if(prevIsNum){
        prevIsNum = false;
        ints.add(Int32.Parse(string.Concat(chars.SubArray(startI,lenI)));
    }
 }
 return ints;
}
```

Comment: This will work if the user is expecting one integer per string, however, if it can contain multiple, then it won' work.

Comment: `Where` instead of `TakeWhile` should fix it. Also, `ToCharArray` is not required, Where (and TakeWhile as well) require an `IEnumerable`, and string is `IEnumerable`. You will need a check for a string containing no digits, since `Int32.Parse`will throw on empty string